# Using the word "about"

Tags: grammar, conversations

It's probably easier to explain the situation because I know there are multiple ways in which "about" could be used.

I am speaking with a friend and I tell them I went to a meeting. The next thing I would like to say is "the meeting was about leaving Japan"

To generalize this grammar point even more I guess I'm asking how I would make I sentence that say "this is about this"

I have a super basic understanding of Japanese so I'm trying to learn as I message/slash talk to people.

Comment: hint: look up Aについて

Comment: Is there anything special about the way I conjugate the verb? Is it short form?

Comment: You can treat it as a set adverb and not conjugate it at all. For further options you can just look up "regarding" in an English ⇒ Japanese dictionary. Also, the reason why your question is downvoted is probably because it is a translation request, and you haven't shown your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

日本から出国することについての会議でした。

にほんからしゅっこくすることについてのかいぎでした。

nihon kara shukkoku suru koto ni tsuite no kaigi deshita.

japan from leaving-country doing about in regard meeting was.

The meeting was about leaving Japan.

...

So if you were to say this: 日本から出国する it would mean "I am leaving Japan", but because you put "koto" to normalise it, then "ni tsuite" to tell them the following words are in regards to it, then "no" to show the meeting was *for* what came before it.

This is quite complex grammar to get your head around if you're a beginner. If you're having trouble trying to understand it, I'd suggest studying から、について、こと separately to this example, then come back and apply what you've studied to your question.